# Stations of the Exodus far into Canaan

Tags: tanach, eretz-yisrael, shemot-exodus

Why is it that certain Exodus stations such as Libnah, Rissah, and Mount Shapher are so far into the actual Promised land of Canaan? Were the Israelites drifting into Canaan unknowingly?

Comment: Jordan, welcome to Mi Yodeya! We hope you'll like the place and decide to stay. Please note that, if you register, you'll be able to log in from other locations. That way, the site can better keep track of your contributions and provide you with a better experience.

Comment: Possibly related: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16360252#16360252

Answer (score 1):

They were wandering for 40 years on purpose.